# Iterating the collection object and inserting into db using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am very new to Node js and trying to iterating each item from collection using for loop and inserting data to Database.

And i have implemented the below code but it inserting only the last object from collection.

i also want to grab out parameter value for each request..  and i need to map with request

does any one save my time.

Below is the code.

```
       app.post('/api/upload/UpdateQualityExcel',function(req,res){

             UpdateQualityExcel_Flag = req.param('Flag');

             body_data=req.body;

             UpdateQualityExcel_res_data=[];

               // var i=1;
            for(i=0;i<body_data.EXCEL_ROWS.length;i++)
            {

                Postdata(UpdateQualityExcel_Flag, body_data.EXCEL_ROWS[i], function(id) {
                    console.log(id);    
                }); 

            }

         });


        function Postdata(UpdateQualityExcel_Flag, EXCEL_ROWS, cb) {

            sql.close();
            sql.connect(config, function (err) {

                if (err) console.log(err);
                  //create Request object
                var request = new sql.Request();

                console.log(EXCEL_ROWS);

                request.input('p_Flag', sql.VarChar, UpdateQualityExcel_Flag)
                request.input('p_ProjectCode', sql.NVarChar, EXCEL_ROWS.PROJECT_CODE);
                request.input('p_ActivityId',sql.INT,EXCEL_ROWS.ACTIVITY_ID);
                request.input('p_ActivityName', sql.VarChar, EXCEL_ROWS.ACTIVITY_NAME);
               request.output('po_Message',sql.VarChar)

                // query to the database and get the records
                request.execute("[dbo].[ARA_SP_ACTION_QualityExcelUpdate]").then(function(recordSet) {

                      if (recordSet == null || recordSet.length === 0)
                        return;

                    // res.send(recordset);
                    cb("test");


                }).catch(function (err) {         
                    console.log(err);

                });
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Postdata` being asynchronous, we can see that we have multiple instance of it running simultaneously.

Being said, they all use of the global variable `sql`. I bet there is some conflicts here.

First `Postdata` open the connection in order to push and then an other instance of `Postdata` close it.

I recommand you to proceed that way :

- Open the connection
- Perform all the insert simultaneously
- Close the connection

---

**EDIT**

Here is some code to help you through your issue, it's a start obviously :)

```
function postdata(UpdateQualityExcel_Flag, EXCEL_ROWS) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // 
    // ... do stuff ...
    // 
    request.execute("[dbo].[ARA_SP_ACTION_QualityExcelUpdate]")
      .then(resolve)
      .catch(reject);
  });
}
```

---

```
// Call all postData
Promise.all(body_data.EXCEL_ROWS.map(x => postData(UpdateQualityExcel_Flag, x)))
  .then((rets) => {
    // All your answers are here
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // You got here in case of error
  });
```

Comment: Thanks so much ..  i also want to grab out parameter value for each request..  and i need to map with request